# indexof string matching from data base and runtime text

Tags: java, mysql

I want to make website blocker in my web browser, so I made a database which contain the names of website. Now I want to check the string from database with `indexOf` method, but it is giving me an error while I am trying to check. Please tell me where my mistake is. Rest of the code is correct and working only database part is not working.

```
public void loadURL(final String url) {
    try {
        Connection myconnection;
        myconnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bookmarks", "roo    t", "");
        try {
            String q = "select * from block where url=?";
            PreparedStatement mysat = myconnection.prepareStatement(q);
            ResultSet myresult = mysat.executeQuery();
            int index1;
            while (myresult.next()) {
                String s2 = myresult.setString("url");
                String s1 = txtURL.getText();
                index1 = s1.indexOf(s2);
            }
            if (index1 == -1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "You Cannot access this website", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String tmp = toURL(url);

                        if (tmp == null) {
                            tmp = toURL("http://" + url);
                        }
                        engine.load(tmp);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            myconnection.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation so your code is readable please?

Answer (score 1):

if you use `PreparedStatement` you have to set a
value for each `?` marker:

```
String q="select * from block where url=?";
PreparedStatement mysat=myconnection.prepareStatement(q);
mysat.setString(1,"www.google.com");
```

without you have an invalid sql syntax.